# How to change rive animation size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, rive

I tried covering the rive animation widget with many widgets but the animations remains big.

How can I change the animation size?

```
    const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                  'assets/rave/rotating-crown.riv',
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
              ),
```

The result is very large and I want it very small like a loading indicator.
[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROId4.png)

I tried widgets like Container, SizedBox, FittedBox.

Comment: Did you manage to make it fit the parent size?

Answer (score 0):

I show it like below and it works for me

```
Container(
 height: 180.0,
 child: Rive(
  artboard: _riveArtboard!,
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Rive'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              width: 80,
              child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                'assets/avatar.riv',
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image]